# IntellIJ CreateProcess error=206 while running spring-boot

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Hi few days ago without any problems I could run the `mvn spring-boot:run` command, and it runs the application without problems. But today I've tried do it again and I am getting this error `CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long` I tried, to add `<property name="dynamic.classpath" value="true"/>` to the `workspace.xml` file and after that I restared my IDE, but it does not help. Have someone similar issue as I have? Maybe someone will know how to fix that, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running gwtCompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501933/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-gwtc)